# wp_mail 550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with my Contact Form 7. This form sometimes works sometimes doesn't.

I tried to debug code and discovered that problem is in wordpress wp_mail() function.

At the one point wp_mail() function will cal get_lines() function, here is source code for get_lines():

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-smtp.php#L820

When everything is ok get_lines() will return $data with this content:

```
354  Go ahead e33sm9178769qgf.42 - gsmtp
```

When it fails get_lines() will return $data with this content:

```
550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded. u1sm14669850qat.27 - gsmtp
```

So what can cause this error, is possible that my receive email hase to much emails in inbox or something else?

Answer (score 0):

From the error code I assume you are using gmail's SMTP to send the emails. Gmail has a daily limit of around 500 emails if I remember correctly.
If you try to send more, you will get such an error...

Comment: How can I check which SMTP am I using? I doubt that my server will sent 500 emails per day. When I testing this, I am able to send couple emails 2-4 and then for next about 2 hours I am getting this error, and after 2 hours I can again send couple emails.

Comment: First check your WP installation to see if you have a plugin that forces wp_mail to user an SMTP server (like the WP SMTP plugin). If not, you should ask your host about this error, maybe the limit is lower than 500, or maybe there is another reason.